# How we can connect React Native App to octobercms backend?

Tags: react-native, octobercms

We are developing new app, and we choose octobercms like backend.

How to connect React Native with octobercms and login with JWT.

Tks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you can not :(**

but you can create a backend API system to sarve and manage your data for your React APP,

> mabye this video series can help you to know about how to you can, on
>   this viedo use Octobercms as backend api system and use vue.js as Frontend
>   Framework same like octobercms and react etc....

https://watch-learn.com/series/creating-rent-car-app-vue-and-october

i hope help you